# MVC6 Access DbContext From Classes Not Related To Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am developing a ASP.Net5 MVC6 website Using EF7.

I wanted to access DbContext from one of my classes which is not being called from Controller.

Is it possible to access from there? If yes then please guide me a little so that I can learn how to do it.

So far searched a lot from GitHub and stackoverflow. Very little information on this topic.

If i need to inject to my class then how should I do it?

```
    public class CarAppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BodyType> BodyTypes { get; set; }
}

public Class NotificationManager
{
    CarAppContext ctx;
    public NotificationManager(CarAppContext AppCtx)
    {
        ctx = AppCtx;
    }
    public void SendNotification(Car HisCar, UserNotification HisNotification)
    {
        //need to check he has subscribed or not
        //ctx is null here
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. The context has nothing to do with controllers. A controller often utilizes the context to do some kind of work, but that doesn't mean you have to have a context in your controller or that you can't create an instance of your context outside of a controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `new CarAppContext()`.

But if you want to use Dependency Injection instead, you will need to make sure that

1. You have registered both CarAppContext and NotificationManager with the dependency injection container (generally done in Startup.Configure)
2. Instantiate NotificationManager from dependency injection

Not surprised you haven't found docs. As ASP.NET 5 is still in beta, our docs haven't been written yet. When its ready, there will be more posted here: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is "viral" concept and you have to use it overall in application - pass dependencies via parameters/properties and have single (or few of) registration root. So the answer is - register `NotificationManager` as dependency.

Even Microsoft's implementation of dependency injection is abstracted enough, so you could easy have kind of classes for each component registers dependencies (like Ninject modules).

Answer (score 0):

Note: Make sure to add this to your file...

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
```